# Delegate on subView

Tags: ios, uitableview, ipad, swift3, subviews

I have 4 `UIViewController` namely vcA, vcB, vcC and vcD. Now, vcB has a `tableView` with two rows. And vcB is subViewed on vcA with one half side like iPad's setting screen. Till here, its working fine, but i required if I click on vcB's tableView's first cell, then vcC should be subViewed on other half side, similarly by selecting vcB's tableview's second cell vcD should be subViewed and vcC should remove.

Here is my screen:

[image: iPad Screen]

Suppose u select "Select Country", the other vcC's view should subviewd & similary by selecting "Notification" vcD should be subViewed and vcC should remove. , and don't worry about frame, i will set that. And assume that the parent view is vcA here.

Here, I tried with `delegate` but on subViews `delegate` is not working I think, it can be Possible through `NSNotificationCenter` but is there any other way to do that ?

Thanks Any help will be appreciated.

**Updated**

Following way I'm using for get the result. But I know its not the correct way, and also not happening what i'm looking for.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        print(indexPath.section)
        print(indexPath.row)
        if UIDevice.Display.typeIsLike == UIDevice.DisplayType.ipad {

            let iPadVc = iPadSettingViewController()

            if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0 {

                var sliderVC: SettingsViewController! = nil

                sliderVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsViewController") as! SettingsViewController

                sliderVC.view.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: 64, width: CGFloat((iPadVc.view.frame.size.width)/2.4), height: CGFloat(iPadVc.view.frame.size.height-64))
                iPadVc.view?.addSubview(sliderVC.view)


            }
            else if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 2 {

                var countryVC : CountryViewController! = nil

                countryVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CountryViewController") as! CountryViewController

                countryVC.view.frame = CGRect(x:CGFloat((iPadVc.view.frame.size.width)/2.4), y: 64, width: CGFloat((iPadVc.view.frame.size.width) - (iPadVc.view.frame.size.width)/2.4), height: CGFloat(iPadVc.view.frame.size.height-64))

                iPadVc.view?.addSubview(countryVC.view)

            }


        }
}
```

Comment: add the code of view controller replacement, which you tried. Is that only for iPad. are you supporting iPhone also?

Comment: @Subramanian it is for iPad only for the time being, and for iPhone the screen will appear differently, i made that all for iPhone, but stuck in for iPad. :/

Comment: can you add the code which you have tried?

Comment: @Subramanian I updated my Question.

Comment: you allocated 'iPadVc' and without presenting you are adding the countryVC view.. You just allocated the vc but the vc `view` will be null at the time of you are adding.

Comment: @Subramanian Then what should I do here..? I started to use NotificationCenter, and it is working, but it is not correctway I think :/ Any suggestion ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148616/discussion-between-subramanian-and-abhishek-mitra).

Comment: wait, I will add suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You allocated 'iPadVc' and without presenting you are trying to add the `countryVC` view.it's wrong.  You just allocated the vc but the vc `view` will be `nil` at the time of you are adding.

My suggestion : Pass the `vcA` object reference to `vcB` while adding a `vcB.view` to `vcA.view`

```
class vcA: UIViewController {

   func loadSlideVC() {
     viewcontrollerB = //Initialize the vcB 
     viewControllerB.containerVC = self
     //Add the view to vaA
   }
}

class vcB: UIViewController {
  weak var containerVC: vcA?

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  if UIDevice.Display.typeIsLike == UIDevice.DisplayType.ipad {
     if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0 {

        var sliderVC: SettingsViewController! = nil
        sliderVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsViewController") as! SettingsViewController
        containerVC?.view?.addSubview(sliderVC.view)
     }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: SliderVC will be fixed as it in screen, Suppose i select country, then beside SliderVC, it will addSubView the Country Viewcontrollers view.

Comment: Exactly Same as iPad's setting screen.

Comment: What is the vc you are adding the when click the country from slideVC?